# htaccess redirect from wrong URL (Laravel)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, laravel

I am using Laravel

Unfortunately Google is picking up the URLs wrong. For example, a page such as: `www.domain.co.uk/article/hello-world` has been indexed in Google as `www.domain.co.uk/public/index.php/article/hello-world`.

When you visit the site, all the URLs seem correct and the `www.domain.co.uk/article/hello-world` URL shows the page as expected, but I guess Google bots are using the `.htaccess` and viewing the long URL instead

(I had put the public folder which comes with Laravel in public_html)

The .htaccess in public_html has:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [l]
```

And there is an additional `.htaccess` in the `public_html/public` folder:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Does anyone know of any solutions to this issue?

I have tried rewrite rules to redirect the URL when `public/index.php` is the URL but I am having zero luck. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be somewhat off-topic for this site, maybe serverfault would provide better answers.  However one tip I can give you is go to Google's webmaster tools https://www.google.com/webmasters/ and you have options to fix things directly with google

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced by your host to include your files only in the document root, then surely you need only one `.htaccess` file in the root itself?

Move the file from `public/` to the root, and change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```